# How to create php function with output true or false given array all sequence number 1 to n

Tags: php, arrays

please help make php function that check whether a given array of integer consists all sequence number from 1 to N. Each number can only appear once in array. Output true/false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559542/more-concise-way-to-check-to-see-if-an-array-contains-only-numbers-integers then check if array has negative ints and check unique values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates

Comment: You need to add a sample array so that we know what you mean. And include what you have tried.

Comment: @sam can you use: `array_key_exists`, `max`, `count`?

Comment: @DavidWinder i'm beginner , so max i do , count i do , but array i'm trying

Comment: input : array(2,3,1,4);
  output : true
  
input : array(2,5,3,4);
output : false (because not start from 1)

input : array(1,3,4,2,5,6,3)
output : false (because 3 appears twice)

input : array(1,2,3,6,5,4,7);
output : true

input : array(1,2,3,5,4,7,8);
output : false (because missing number 6)

Comment: Create a php function that check whether a given array of integer consists all sequence number from 1 to N. Each number can only appear once in array. Position of number can be random. Output true/false. (You are not allowed to use php built in array sort function) actually this its my completed question , thank you Mister , and when i have test in yogyakarta test i don't know and i'm start to need help and learning how can be profesional programe thank Mr.David

Answer (score 1):

Since you say *integer consists all sequence number from 1 to N. Each number can only appear once in array*
That means if we compare the array with a range() then the output is true/false.
You can also include a sort in case the arrays are not sorted.

```
$arr1 = [2,1,3,4,5,6,6,7];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$arr3 = [1,3,4,5,6,7];
$arr4 = [1,5,6,7,4,3,2];

// sort arrays
sort($arr1);
sort($arr2);
sort($arr3);
sort($arr4);

$n = 7;
$range = range(1,$n);
// or $range(min($array),$n); or $range(min($array),max($array)); depedning on how you want it set up


var_dump($arr1 == $range); //false
var_dump($arr2 == $range); //true
var_dump($arr3 == $range); //false
var_dump($arr4 == $range); //true
```

https://3v4l.org/DMe46

---

With the added information, we can use array_intersect and count.
Array intersect returns the matching items in the array.
If we then count them we see if they match.

```
$arr1 = array(2,3,1,4);
$arr2 = array(2,5,3,4);
$arr3 = array(1,3,4,2,5,6,3);


$range1 = range(1,max($arr1));
$range2 = range(1,max($arr2));
$range3 = range(1,max($arr3));


var_dump(count($range1) == count(array_intersect($arr1, $range1)));
// true

var_dump(count($range2) == count(array_intersect($arr2, $range2)));
// false

var_dump(count($range3) == count(array_intersect($arr3, $range3)));
// false
```

https://3v4l.org/7Hdll

Comment: Notice OP request **1** to N

Comment: I think the `min()`, `max()` solution covers any combination of numbers

Comment: Yes?? You want me to capitalize my `$n`? @DavidWinder

Comment: No, start from 1 and not 0

Comment: Ok. Didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: ok thank you very much friends, I appreciate my clearer question like this You are not allowed to use php built in array sort function
Example
  input : array(2,3,1,4);
  output : true
  
input : array(2,5,3,4);
output : false (because not start from 1)

input : array(1,3,4,2,5,6,3)
output : false (because 3 appears twice)


input : array(1,2,3,5,4,7,8);
output : false (because missing number 6)

Comment: I'm allowed to use any functions I want! If you want help on this page make sure to go to the help section before asking a question again

Answer (score 0):

- Each number has to be an integer
- Each number has to be bigger than the previous number
- Negative number are allowed.

> ```
> function testInt($my_array)
> {
>   $prevval = null;
>   foreach ($my_array as $val) {
>       if ((filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) === false) {
>           return false;
>       }
>       if ($prevval !== null) {
>           if ($val <= $prevval) {
>               return false;
>           }
>       }
>       $prevval = $val;
>   }
>   return true;
> }
> ```

```
$test1 = [-1, "4", 5, 7];
$test2 = [0, 1, 2, 100];
$test3 = [1, 4, 4, 100];
$test4 = [1, 5, 4, 1000];
$test5 = [5, 6, 7, "50"];

var_dump(testInt($test1));
bool(true)
var_dump(testInt($test2));
bool(true)
var_dump(testInt($test3));
bool(false)
var_dump(testInt($test4));
bool(false)
var_dump(testInt($test5));
bool(true)
```

Comment: ok thank you very much friends, I appreciate my clearer question like this You are not allowed to use php built in array sort function
Example
  input : array(2,3,1,4);
  output : true
  
input : array(2,5,3,4);
output : false (because not start from 1)

input : array(1,3,4,2,5,6,3)
output : false (because 3 appears twice)


input : array(1,2,3,5,4,7,8);
output : false (because missing number 6)